# Send a number instead of a string to Angular's matToolTip as part of mat-icon-button? Alternatively, convert number to string in an Angular template?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following line:

`[matTooltip]="ratingId + 1"`, which is part of the arguments for a Material Design button.

Normally this would all be fine, but we are using Typescript. `ratingId` is a number. 1 is also a number. `[matTooltip]` would like a string.

I found many questions on converting numbers to strings in Typescript, but none for doing it in the template.

Comment: `[matTooltip]="" + (ratingId + 1)` :: concatenate empty string to result of calculation

Comment: @RandyCasburn that unfortunately gives me `Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.`

Comment: @RandyCasburn fixed it by adding quotes around it the entire thing to the right of the equals sign.

Answer (score 0):

the final output of matTooltip should be a string but you can bind anything that eventually turns into string. for example, you can use a ternary operator like this:

`[matTooltip]="!isTrue ? name : ''"`

in your case you can use like this:
`[matTooltip]="'ratingId + 1'"`